# Javascript slideshow adding links

Tags: javascript, function

This script will cycle through the images but I cannot figure out how to get it to recognize the links that are associated with each image. I thought I could just use the same counter "i" to move through the link array, but it doesn't work.

```
var images = [
"Image1.jpg",
"Image2.jpg",
"Image3.jpg"
];

var weblinks = [
"http://google.com",
"http://yahoo.com",
"http://dell.com"
];
var num = images.length;
var i = 0;
var t;

function play() {
if(typeof t === 'undefined') {
    t = setInterval(next, 2000);
}
}

function Stop() {
if(t) clearInterval(t);
}

function next() {
if(++i >= num) i = 0;
document.getElementById('img').src = images[i];
document.getElementById('link').src = webLinks[i];

}

function previous() {
if(--i < 0) i = num-1;
document.getElementById('img').src = images[i];
document.getElementById('link').src = webLinks[i];

}

window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById('img').src = images[0];
document.getElementById('link').src = webLinks[0];
a.href=link[i];

}
```

The HTML

```
<table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding top="0" align="center">
<tr>
<td><input type="button" value="Back" onclick="previous()"/></td>
<td align="center"><a id="link" href="#" target="_self"><img src="Image1.jpg" alt=""  id="img"/></a></td>
<td><input type="button" value="Next" onclick="next()"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" align="center" height="50"><input type="button" value="Play" onclick="play()" />
  <input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="Stop()" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `document.getElementById('link').src` with `document.getElementById('link').href` -  you're changing the wrong attribute of the link.

EDIT: also change `var weblinks` to `var webLinks` - JavaScript is case-sensitive.
And remove `a.href=link[i];`, which doesn't do anything (since a isn't defined, nor is link).

Comment: There was a second error - I've edited my answer to include the fix

Comment: /facepalm. Thanks. It works fine now, despite IE claiming it rendered the page with an error.